# Include entire folder with Symfony and Twig javascripts and styles

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

Is it possible to include an entire folder with the Twig included in Symfony2?

Basically, I'd like to be able to separate my Javascript objects into their own folder for increased readability, but then be able to include all of those back in to one file to present to the client.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: I technically mean with Assetic, using the javascripts and stylesheets tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to have the {% stylesheets %} and {% javascripts %} code in separate twig templates? Or just to have the js/css files in separate directories?

If you mean the latter, then that's the standard use of Assetic. The example case in the docs describes exactly that.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Note that while in the dev environment they will still be separated. In the prod environment they are combined. (This is configurable in app/config/config.yml)

If you are looking to have the {% stylesheets %} and {% javascripts %} tags in separate twig template but have them compile to a single JS/CSS file, this is not currently possible. But I believe they are working on this ability with the next major release.

Comment: Yeah. I am currently using that, but I have to list each file individually. I would like it if it would simply grab all the files in the folder and combine them, so then I can simply use them in my Javascript without having to make sure they are created.

Comment: It will do expansion of an asterisk... just do something like "@FooBundle/Resources/public/css/*.css"

Comment: It would be awesome if I could get that to work, because it sounds like it's exactly what I want. However, I tried something like this: "@MyProject/Resources/public/scripts/*" and I get an error (though something like "@MyProject/Resources/public/scripts/script.js" works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: So, I had my includes in a separate file and import that template in, it causes the issue. If I have it directly in the template, it doesn't... weird. But, it seems to work. Thanks a ton, not sure how I missed that feature earlier. =)